# Не получается подключить библиотеку через go get

Tags: golang, библиотеки

Пытаюсь подключить библиотеку для работы с toml через go get.
В терминале ввожу `go get https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml`
На что выводится следующее сообщение

```
go: writing stat cache: mkdir /usr/local/go/pkg/mod: permission denied
go: downloading github.com/BurntSushi/toml v0.3.1
go get github.com/BurntSushi/toml: mkdir /usr/local/go/pkg/mod: permission denied
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Очевидно, что у вас нет прав на запись в данную папку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

при импорте вы же не указываете `import "https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml"`?

`go help get` выдает

> Get downloads the packages named by the import paths, along with their
> dependencies.

значит нужно выполнить `go get github.com/BurntSushi/toml` без `https://`

> mkdir /usr/local/go/pkg/mod: permission denied

ошибка говорит о том, что у пользователья нет прав на изменение директории $GOPATH. Это происходит, когда вы работаете с go с правами root-а. 
Надо вернуть права на директорию, например, изменив владельца

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/go/ && sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/go/`

Comment: Вообще-то при вводе `go get https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml` выдается `invalid import path: malformed import path "https:/github.com/BurntSushi/toml": invalid char ':'` (для 1.13.8 версии Go), в то время как ошибка конкретно говорит что `mkdir /usr/local/go/pkg/mod: permission denied`, так что это частичный ответ.

Comment: точно. права. не хотите ответить самому?

Comment: Я уже поместил комментарий по этому в вопросе.